Facebook Graph API: Unable to Retrieve "from" Field in Live Video Comments if users without any app roles
I'm using the Facebook JavaScript SDK to retrieve the comments for a live video (with the page access token), using the following Graph API request:
GET /{live-video-id}/comments

However, I'm encountering an issue where the "from" field is only available for comments made by users with Tester App roles:
{
    "from": {
        "name": "Toni Wong",
        "id": "26125913430....."
    },
    "message": "m+1",
    "created_time": "2024-07-10T10:10:19+0000",
    "id": "992451439....._854049766....."
}

For comments made by other users without any app roles, the "from" field is missing in the response:
{
    "message": "s+1",
    "created_time": "2024-07-10T10:10:35+0000",
    "id": "992451439....._139887616....."
}

My app has the following permissions:

public_profile
Live Video API
instagram_manage_messages
pages_manage_metadata
email
pages_messaging
instagram_manage_comments
pages_read_engagement
business_management
instagram_basic
pages_read_user_content
pages_show_list
pages_manage_engagement

Have I missed any necessary permissions or configurations that could be causing this issue?
